# How to use different sender address in iMessage when messaging different contacts?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, settings

My Apple account has my phone number and my email address. In iMessage settings, it allows me to select the default sender address (phone number or email).

I want to know if it is possible to use phone number when I and messages to some contacts, but use email address for some other contacts?

For example, let's say I have two contacts A and B. I want it this way: When I send an iMessage to A, they see the message is from my phone number, but when I send an iMessage to B, they see the message is from my email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature Apple ships for iOS 17 or lower in the contacts app or the messages app.